# A good java library or framework for metadata driven approach?

Tags: java, metadata

I am pretty new to Java and I have a project need to use metadata driven approach design since it has more than 200 different objects and those objects could be changed in the future. My question is if there is any library or framework that I can quickly implement this approach in java? I was thinking hibernate before but I don't think it support metadata driven design any more. Any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's been my experience that the metadata approach is a bad idea.  The ability to constrain based on domain knowledge goes out the window and the program ends up being procedural rather than object-oriented.  Usually a better look at the business objects solves the need to overuse metadata.

Answer (score 2):

EMF is a very good choice for Model Driven Development. You should take a look at it. Follow the below two tutorials to see if that fits for you.

1. [High level introduction](http://miloud.webs.com/emf.htm)
2. [Eclipse Modeling page](http://eclipse.org/modeling/)
3. [EMF 2nd edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321331885)